# jQuery attribute disable not working

Tags: jquery

I'm try to disable (and remove) some attributes in jQuery, but it seems not working when value is changed and set to "disabled" some fields. This script runs when a value of drop-down box is changed.

Here code below:

```
$(".tipo_frete").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()  == "FOB" ){
        $(".id_transp").attr("disabled");
        $(".id_transp").val("");
        $(".nome_transp").attr("disabled");
        $(".nome_transp").val("");
        $(".valor_frete").attr("disabled");                     
        $(".valor_frete").val("");                      
    }else{
        $(".id_transp").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".valor_frete").removeAttr("disabled");           
        $(".nome_transp").removeAttr("disabled");           
    }
});
```

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: In light of the answers, I think this question is OK, so I'll vote to reopen. (It might close as having too much of a niche solution, though, we'll see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery when you want to get attribute value, must be use *.attr('key')* or *.prop('key')* with one argument, But when you want to set a value to an attribute, you must set two arguments like as *.attr('key', 'value')* or *.prop('key', 'value')*

```
$(".id_transp").attr("disabled", "disabled");

//OR

$(".id_transp").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

use **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

**disable**

```
$(".id_transp").prop("disabled",true);
```

**enable**

```
$(".id_transp").prop("disabled",false);
```

NOTE :  `$(".id_transp").attr("disabled");` you have to pass 2 arguments like `$(".id_transp").attr("disabled",true)`

simplify your code

```
$(".tipo_frete").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "FOB") {
        $(".id_transp,.nome_transp,.valor_frete").val("").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(".id_transp,.nome_transp,.valor_frete").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing another parameter in attr() property. 
Try this:

```
$(".tipo_frete").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()  == "FOB" ){
        $(".id_transp").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(".id_transp").val("");
        $(".nome_transp").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(".nome_transp").val("");
        $(".valor_frete").attr("disabled","disabled");                      
        $(".valor_frete").val("");                      
    }else{
        $(".id_transp").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".valor_frete").removeAttr("disabled");           
        $(".nome_transp").removeAttr("disabled");           
    }
});
```

But when you remove those attibutes, you keep only one parameter inside and it will be removed.

Comment: That was a complete one. It tried to pass two arguments in parameter on removeAttr() instead to do this in attr(). Thanks. Its worked.

Answer (score 1):

element equal to selector '.id_transp';

```
  var $element = $(...);
        $element.prop('disabled', true);
        $element.attr('disabled', true); 

        // The following do not require jQuery
        $element.get(0).disabled = true;
        $element.get(0).setAttribute('disabled', true);
        $element[0].disabled = true;
        $element[0].setAttribute('disabled', true);
```